# Displaying Historical Maps

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have an application where I need to show historical maps. Is there a way to use the Google API for that, ie show a map of Europe for the year 1800, 1900 etc, with different borders and country names?

I am not particular to any language and also welcome solutions that might not involve the Google API but another library or service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware about such functionality in Google Maps right now. However, it should be noted that Google Earth has several historical maps (including a world map from 1790, a 1833 US map, a 1680 map of Tokyo, and a 1716 map of Paris), so chances are they will add this functionality to Google Maps at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesnt have historic ability built in but it does have code to allow you to tile, zoom and display your own images.

Also take note that for commercial application I beleive you might need to license it.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps support having different tiles (the map picture) under them. So if you can get a map of 1800 then you can show it in the map (but probably you would need a high resolution map).

And so on.